# Trouble Understanding Vulkan Shader

Tags: glsl, vulkan

From the [Vulkan Tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Shader_modules):

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

out gl_PerVertex {
    vec4 gl_Position;
};

vec2 positions[3] = vec2[](
    vec2(0.0, -0.5),
    vec2(0.5, 0.5),
    vec2(-0.5, 0.5)
);

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(positions[gl_VertexIndex], 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**Question 1:** What does this designate?

```
out gl_PerVertex {
    vec4 gl_Position;
};
```

**Question 2:** What explains the syntax `vec2 positions[3] = vec2[](...)`? To initialize the array, shouldn't the syntax be

```
vec2 positions[3] = {
    vec2(0.0, -0.5),
    vec2(0.5, 0.5),
    vec2(-0.5, 0.5)
};
```

Is this shader-specific syntax, or can `arrayType[](...)` be used as a constructer in C++ also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question 1**: What does this designate?

This

```
out gl_PerVertex {
    vec4 gl_Position;
};
```

is an [Output Interface Block](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Input_and_output). (See further [GLSL Specification - 4.3.9 Interface Blocks](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf))

> **Question 2**: What explains the syntax vec2 positions[3](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Input_and_output) = vec2? To initialize the array, shouldn't the syntax be ...

No

See [Array constructors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Array_constructors)

> Arrays can be constructed using array constructor syntax. In this case, the 
>   type also contains the [] array notation:
>
> ```
> const float array[3] = float[3](2.5, 7.0, 1.5);
> ```

See [GLSL Specification - 4.1.11 Initializers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf):

> If an initializer is a list of initializers enclosed in curly braces, the variable being declared must be a
>   vector, a matrix, an array, or a structure.
>
> ```
> int i = { 1 }; // illegal, i is not a composite
> ```
>
> ....
>
> All of the following declarations result in a compile-time error.
>
> ```
> float a[2] = { 3.4, 4.2, 5.0 }; // illegal
> ```
>
> ....
>
> If an initializer (of either form) is provided for an unsized array, the size of the array is determined by the
>   number of top-level (non-nested) initializers within the initializer. All of the following declarations create
>   arrays explicitly sized with five elements:
>
> ```
> float a[] = float[](3.4, 4.2, 5.0, 5.2, 1.1);
> float b[] = { 3.4, 4.2, 5.0, 5.2, 1.1 };
> float c[] = a; // c is explicitly size 5
> float d[5] = b; // means the same thing
> ```